# LINQ to SQL OrderBy using string varible in C# 6

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, sql-order-by, c#-6.0

I'm using **`C# Version 6`**, I having a string variable and I'm trying to sort the LINQ to SQL database table, earlier its working fine but now its not giving appropriate sorting result.

```
using (var db = new DBEntity()) {
    var propertyInfo = nameof(Client.ClientName);
    var iQuery = db.Clients.OrderByDescending(i => propertyInfo);
    foreach (var item in iQuery.ToList()) {
        Console.WriteLine(item.ClientName);
    }
}
```

Note: I refereed lots of tutorial in Stack overflow blog and other sites but I can't able to find.

Kindly assist me, whats wrong in my code.

Table Structure and Data

```
ClientName   ClientStatus
______________________________
Emma         Active
Harry        Active
```

In both Ascending and Descending I'm getting the same output

```
ClientName   ClientStatus
______________________________
Emma         Active
Harry        Active
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot just pass name (string) of the property which you want to use for sorting. You should use property selector expression:

```
var iQuery = db.Clients.OrderByDescending(c => c.ClientName);
```

---

**Expalanation**:

LINQ to SQL generates SQL query from expressions which you are passing to query operators. E.g. for ordering you should pass a property selector expression:

```
OrderByDescending(x => x.SomeProperty)
```

LINQ to SQL will use this *expression* to get database field which is mapped to given property (remember, you can change mapping). And generates something like

```
ORDER BY SomeProperty DESC
```

But when you are passing string as

```
OrderByDescending(x => "SomeProperty")
```

The best think LINQ can do is to sort by string literal which you are passing:

```
ORDER BY N'SomeProperty' DESC
```

Of course such kind of 'sorting' will not change order of query result

Comment: Dynamically I get the property name. Moreover the above statement runs without any build error.

Comment: @Mastero dynamically you don't sort anythign

Comment: Kindly let me know why?

Comment: @Mastero take a look on explanation